# How to test catch block of a Typescript function code using mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have typescript class with some functions in it. Each function has a try catch block where upon hitting the catch it returns a pre defined response.

I am writing unit tests using mocha and chai and I am having trouble trying to explicitly hit the catch blocks.

For example, consider this simple function below

```
public async verifyCode(email: string, code: string) {
        try {
            let result: CodeInterface | null = //call db to get matching code
            
            if(result === null) {
                return {status: 401, message: INCORRECT_FELLOWSHIP_CODE_MESSAGE}; 
            }
            
            return result._id;
        } catch (error) {
            Logger.log(LoggerLogTypes.ERROR, {
                class_name: "LaunchServiceImpl",
                function_name: "verifyFellowshipCode",
                message: error.message,
                stack: error.stack,
                additional_info: {
                    code
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I want to write a test case where I can just send the control directly to the catch block to get the false value. This is a very simplistic example but in few other functions I am doing a lot more in the catch block.

My mocha unit test looks like this:

```
it("should go to the catch block and return false in case of exception", async function() {

        let serviceInstance = new MyClass();

        let response = await serviceInstance.verifyCode("john@test.com", "abc123");
        
        // how do I directly jump to the catch block here??
        expect(response).to.equal(false);
    });
```

Comment: You would have to make `call db to get matching code` fail, probably using some kind of test double, but without a [mre] it's hard to say any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function that will throw an error with the message User not found so you can test like this:

```
profileServiceInstance.getProfile('1').catch((err) => {
  expect(() => {
    throw err;
  }).to.throw(Error, 'User not found');
});
```